# Can any piecewise function be represented as a traditional equation?

Tags: continuity, signal-processing

In "Fundamentals of Electrical Engineering" we learned about piecewise functions for the "unit-step" and "ramp" which are represented by 
$f(x)= \begin{cases}0, & \text{if }x< 0 \\ 1, & \text{if }x>0\end{cases}$ and
$f(x)= \begin{cases}0, & \text{if }x< 0 \\ x, & \text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}$ respectively. I was bored in calculous class and determined these functions could be represented in traditional algebra by $f(x)= \frac{|x|}{x} \cdot \frac12 + \frac12$ and $f(x)= \frac{x + |x|}2$ So this got me thinking. Can any piecewise function be represented as a traditional equation? Just as an example, how about this one:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
   5, & \text{if }x=0 \\
   x^2, & \text{if }x<0 \\
   \sqrt{x} & \text{if }x>0
\end{cases}$$

edit: For the sake of the question, substitute $\sqrt{x^2}$ for $|x|$

Comment: What is to be accepted as traditional? Whatever you accept, I assume all your traditional functions are continuous (in their domain of definition), which makes the composition of non-continuous functions impossible.

Comment: I like this question, and I voted it up. But I also share Hagen's view: what constitutes a "traditional" equation? In particular, what makes $|x|$ traditional, and $f(x)=(x+|x|)/2$ non-traditional?

Comment: If you use the absolute value function, you're still using something that's defined piecewise; you've just hidden the piecewise part of the definition.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant With your second question you miss the OP's point, I guess. The *expression* $(x+|x|)/2$ is fine for hime in contrast to anything using `\begin{cases}..\end{cases}`

Comment: I mean anything that is not a piecewise function. And it is not necessary that it be continuous. The example I gave for a "unit step" is discontinuous at 0.

Comment: @kennycoc Your unit step is continuous in its domain of definition. And what does "Anything that is not a piecewise function" mean? Do you accept limits, for example?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs See my edit

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, we apparently agree that more clarification is needed, even if we aren't reading it the same way. :-)

Comment: Any equation that does not use different cases is fine

Comment: I switched the signs to prevent it from needing imaginary numbers, that was unintentional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial step is to come up with an acceptable way to describe indicator functions, i.e. for certain subsets $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ to replace the piecewise definition
$$1_S(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in S\\0&\text{if }x\notin S\end{cases} $$
with something not involving piecewise, but only "traditional" definitions. Provided that taking limits is allowed as "traditional", we should accept the functions 
$$\begin{align}\max\{x,y\} &=\frac{x+2}{2}+\left|\frac{x-y}{2}\right|\\
\min\{x,y\} &=x+y-\max\{x,y\}\\
1_{[0,\infty)}(x)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\min\{e^{nx},1\} \\
1_{(-\infty,0]}(x)&=1_{[0,\infty)}(-x)\\
 1_{[a,b)}(x) &=1_{[0,\infty)}(x-a)-1_{[0,\infty)}(x-b)\\
 1_{[a,b]}(x) &=1_{[0,\infty)}(x-a)\cdot1_{[0,\infty)}(b-x)\\
 1_{\{a\}}(x) &=1_{[0,\infty)}(x-a)\cdot 1_{[0,\infty)}(a-x)\end{align}$$
and similar combinations for arbitrary intervals $\subseteq \mathbb R$. With these you get for example 
$$\begin{align}f(x)&= \begin{cases}
   5, & \text{if }x=0 \\
   x^2, & \text{if }x<0 \\
   \sqrt{x} & \text{if }x>0
\end{cases}\\& = 1_{\{0\}}(x)\cdot 5+1_{(-\infty,0)}(x)\cdot x^2+1_{(0,\infty)}(x)\cdot\sqrt x.\end{align} $$
Or, just to make sure, you may want to replace $\sqrt {x}$ with $\sqrt{1_{[0,\infty)}(x)\cdot x}$ (otherwise you'd need a convention that $0$ times undefined is $0$).