Does there always exist a different piecewise formula (that covers wider range of cases) for a piecewise function?
Can an arbitrary function be defined using an expression?
Take the ceiling function for example, it can be described as a piecewise function, however is it possible to exclude points that require a computer to evaluate whether the number satisfies the property.
I want to mean, is it possible to create a formula such that it takes the input and evaluates every input using the same formula rather than switching back and forth with definitions?
Example:
I can define a function $f(x) = x^2$ if $x > 4$ and $3$, if $x$ is equal to or less than $4$. Does there exist a formula for such a function? In other words, can this formula plot the same graph?
Formula for the floor function:
$$-\frac12 + x + \frac1\pi \arctan(\cot \pi x)$$

What are we allowed to build the function out of? is the ceiling function included? if so, we can make any piecewise function with finitely many pieces.

Conditional formulas are still formulas...at some point, whatever you write down has to evaluate a conditional clause.

The issue is that there is no reasonable definition of "piecewise function" to begin with. "Piecewise" is a property of the description of the function, not the function itself. For example, the functions $x\mapsto \sqrt{x^2}$ and the function $f$ such that $f(x)$ that equals $x$ when $x\ge0$ and $-x$ when $x<0$ are the same, but I described the second in a "piecewise" sense.

@lulu I want a formula. In the definition above, I would have to look for definition of the function at the given value. I want an expression that that can evaluate it properly for all values of x.

In any case, even though the terms "piecewise" and "formula" do not really have precise definitions, the only reasonable answer to your question I can think of is: no. You could look up noncomputable functions, perhaps.

does this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677618/1107685 answer your question?

Again, any "formula" you wrote down would obviously have to evaluate the conditional.  Perhaps you mean something like "I have a list of functions that I am willing to use and I would like to know if that list is enough to handle every sort of piecewise condition that might arise."  That might make sense, but of course it would depend on the list.

@ZoeAllen The thing is, that there is a formula for the floor function that involves trigonometric functions and it is not piecewise so the question remains.

@Sanskars it's still not clear what you're asking, because it's still not clear what you're allowing as an acceptable formula. Please specify that first.

If you are referring to something like this then note that these expressions very much rely on evaluating conditionals.  The "best" formula attached to the linked post falls back on the sgn function, which is obviously conditionally defined.

@lulu sorry I am new so don't know how to edit. But I have tried my best to enlist the formula for the floor function in the new edit.

But, of course, that's the same as the formula in the post I linked to, and it is conditional (as it is undefined at integers as it stands).

@ZoeAllen Thanks!

@lulu it works for all value of x, you could even graph it  on Desmos.

Please look at the post I linked to.  The way it works is that you replace the function by the conditional which declares a value at integers.  Thus, to evaluate it you must first decide if the argument is an integer or not.  Desmos is, of course, perfectly happy with conditional definitions.

@Joe And also $|x|$ (the absolute value is the same as the principal square root of the square).

@lulu, I think OP is not asking for a completely conditional-free definition, but merely looking for a compact looking expression (even if it had a conditional definition, but well hidden). In that sense your suggestion of "sgn" (or equivalently heaviside function) is probably all that they are looking for.

@Srini as I say,  the question only makes sense if a list of "allowed " functions is provided.

Like this answer says, you can do this as long as you can describe the indicator functions (as long as you have finitely many pieces). If you're allowing $\arctan$ as an acceptable function, and don't care about undefined points between sections, then we can define the indicator function for an interval in terms of the Heaviside step function $S(x)$, as
$$1\{a<x<b\} = S(x-a) - S(x-b)$$
And $S(x)$ can be defined as
$$S(x) = \lfloor \frac{2e^x}{e^x + 1}  \rfloor$$
where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function. Using the floor function you've constructed using $\arctan$. This definition of $S(x)$ will be undefined at $x=0$, so the value of your function will be undefined at the joins between your pieces, but you've said you don't care about that.
Whether this is of any actual significance is another matter.
